# O que fazer quando a pergunta foi respondida nos comentários?

Tags: suporte

Hoje fiz uma pergunta e ela foi respondida nos **comentários**.

O que eu deveria fazer para agradecer/finalizar a pergunta?

Comment: No máximo, pedir ao usuário que transforme em resposta o comentário, informando a ele que lhe ajudou a resolver. Não tem porquê fechar a pergunta.